# Memory leak in Hibernate session?

Tags: java, hibernate, memory-leaks, hibernate-entitymanager

I am experiencing a memory leak in a Hibernate session.

A long running thread is continuously loading and updating data. While the thread regularily calls `entityManager.clear()` I observe both:

1.) growth in `Session`-size (linear growth since start of application)

2.) growth in execution-time (exponential growth since start of application)

The only thing, that seems to help is to `close()` the entitymanager and re-open it. I have seen this behaviour in several unconnected applications, some with spring, some without, some using the jpa-frontend, some using hibernate natively.

Weird enough: while I have never encountered a hibernate application without this problem, searching the internet comes up blank. What am I (and dozens of other developers) doing wrong?

Comment: hibernate sessions should not run a *long* time, it should be closed in the shot-circuit.

Comment: the hibernate session is bound to the entitymanager and I can't find a possibility to put a different one into the em. At the same time, the entitymanager is bound to the running thread (at least: Spring says so). So: Does the use of hibernate forbid long-running threads?

Comment: How it's bound? Do you obtain it from Spring?

Comment: Yes, using the SpringEntityManagerFactoryUtils (at least in one of the applications)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in hibernate that prevent clear for clearing session cleanly.
See:

- [Improve Memory Management when Post Commit Listeners are enabled](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-3809)
- [Integrate Draft 6 of the JPA 2.1 spec](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7387)

It should be fixed in 4.3.

My workaround is to use short-lived session.